# Am I able to use the full functionalities of GoogleClassroom API without having an educational license?

Tags: google-classroom

Am starting out a new business to improve the literacy rate of kids in Malaysia, and would like to know if I am able to use the full functionalities of the GoogleClassroom API.

My business, has not been approved by an government/or a body that is able to license that I am indeed an educational organisation.

So far, I've been able to pull my classroom data via the API, before I start coding it, would like to know if I will potentially face pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can use Classroom API to build tools. You just need to agree to the Classroom API Term of services.You cann't use Classroom data for advertising purposes.